# Generate all paths through matrix with max N similarity to any other

Tags: c#, matrix, path

I've got a X by Y matrix, and from that I need to generate all possible ways to get from one side (first column) to the other (last column), but only N points on the way can be the same as any other generated combination.

I know that I could generate all combinations and compare them to all other to filter out the ones I want, but for bigger matrices like 16 by 16 the combinations are way to many to generate them all and also to compare each to the rest.

Is there a way to generate the combinations with max N in similarity without having to generate them all?

Example: N=1

```
["a", "a", "a"]
["b", "b", "b"]
["c", "c", "c"]
```

Should generate something like this:
aaa
abb
acc
bba
cca
cab

I've been on this for a few days now and haven't found any good solutions, so any help would be greatly appreciated, and if possible in C#.

Comment: Please explain "I need to generate all possible ways to get from one side to the other". Do you mean go from cells on edges to the opposite edge?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, yes I mean from the first column to the last column.

Comment: Then your second path should be abbb not abb. No? abccc, bbb, bccc, ccc, cbbb, cbaaa, abbcc, cbbaa, Am I getting this?

Comment: The paths can only go through column 1-2-3, so the length can not be longer than 3 characters

Comment: I give up; too much stuff not explained in the question. Feel free to revise it and I will revisit. A better example and explanation will help. Maybe post your entire homework question instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: You should be able to remove them as you generate them: for instance 1. generate aaa, add it; 2. generate aab, compare to added, don't add it; 3. repeat for all combinations; There may be a way to reduce generating combinations (ie aa has been generated, never start with it again, however). I think there's no catch all, you'll have to add efficiencies with these tweaks. Substrings might help you out here.

Comment: Adrian, sorry for being unclear, not sure how to explain it in English any better, also I can't post a question since it's for a work project.
What I want to do is take one letter from column 1, then one from column 2, 3 and so on. Each time I take a 3(the width of the matrix) letter combination it needs to be N characters different than the rest. 
So the combinations you get in the end can be different depending on the order you take them.

Comment: perhaps a hashmap or suffix tree might help eliminate branches early

Comment: Bob2Chiv, I tried that, but for a 16x16 matrix there are so many combinations that don't meet the criteria that it will take way way too long to get the ones that works. But thanks. 
For big matrices picking random combinations and matching them to the previous worked pretty well up to a certain limit where it almost stopped.
Adrian, thanks for the tip, will look in to that.

Comment: In fact I'm sure if you go brute force and compute all combinations a hashmap will definitely help

Comment: I understand, a 16 by 16 matrix allows for 16^16 permutations. I like the idea of a suffix tree; but as I mentioned earlier, that will only get you part of the way. (You would take only one item from each branch with a depth of N or more).

Comment: 16^16 combinations would never fit on my computer, so generating them all would be impossible. Since I don't really need all the possible combinations from 16x16 matching the criteria, I could try randomizing the picking and using the hashmap for comparing until I got enough combinations. Sure is a hard problem to beat.

Comment: Adam King's answer suggests that there are 16^15 paths with N=1 similarity; How do you expect to store these if you have an issue storing 16^16?

Answer (score 0):

Answer = y ^ (x - n)

Ignore your problem in the first instance, and generalise, you have a 3x3 grid. So:

```
x = 3;
y = 3;
n = 1;
```

Therefore you have y^x combinations i.e. 3^3 =  27

If you want to make sure that you are not having a certain amount of matches along the way, you can simply reduce the amount of columns by that amount in order to reduce the amount of permutations.

In your example, N is one, so reduce x by 1 to get an x of 2.

Now 3^2 = 6, which is your given answer.

If you were to scale this up, I believe it would be accurate, but I've had a long week so if I have missed something please feel free to let me know.

**Edit**
Having re-read your question I'm not strictly sure I have understood correctly, I am intrigued so please let me know...

Comment: I think he needs to actually generate the correct paths; but knowing how many (if accurate) could help him escape early.

Comment: Yeah after a re-read I get that impression too. Basically wants every combination of x letters that don't share many letters. Looks like homework!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to immediately reduce space complexity, however, you can use dynamic programming to avoid checking for duplicates thereby reducing the time complexity.  With a little extra effort, usually the space complexity can be reduced in dynamic programming problems as well.

There exists an optimal substructure in the sense that paths are simply a sum of independent but overlapping prefixes (a+a = aa, aa+a = aaa).  Taking this into account we can solve the problem of 3x3 in the following fashion.

Paper and Pencil Method:

Determining the solution of the first choice is already done - a, b, c.
We need to determine the solution of the second choice, third, etc.

Determine prefixes of two by concatenation row + col - the choice available by two columns.

```
    a   b   c
a   aa  ab  ac
b   ba  bb  bc
c   ca  cb  cc
```

Take the prefixes we just created and apply them to the our initial 1x1 solution - row + col

```
    a   b   c
aa  aaa aab aac
ba  baa bab bac
ca  caa cab cac
ab  aba abb abc
bb  bba bbb bbc
cb  cba cbb cbc
ac  aca acb acc
bc  bca bcb bcc
cc  cca ccb ccc
```

An n*n solution would simply be this method repeated n-1 times.

I wrote this out in C# as well

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sizeOf = 3; //size of problem - ex 3x3
        var vals = "abcdefghijklmnop".ToCharArray(); //up to 16 (abc in ex)

        //Create initial problem
        String[] x = new String[sizeOf]; 
        String[] y = new String[sizeOf];

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            x[i] = vals[i].ToString();
            y[i] = vals[i].ToString();
        }

        //hold our solutions
        String[][] result = null;
        String[] temp = x;

        for (int i = 1; i < y.Length; i++)
        {
            result = getCombos(temp, y);

            temp = (from k in result
                    from l in k
                    select l).ToArray();
        }

        //Flatten out solution
        var finalResult = (from k in result
                           from l in k
                           select l).ToList();

        printArray(finalResult);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Count: {0}", finalResult.Count());

    }

    static void printArray(List<String> a)
    {
        foreach (var x in a)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", x);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static String[][] getCombos(String[] x, String[] y)
    {
        //Initialize array to hold solution
        String[][] prefixes = new String[x.Length][];
        for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
        {
            prefixes[j] = new String[y.Length];
        }

        //concat to form solution
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < y.Length; j++)
            {
                prefixes[i][j] = x[i] + y[j];
            }
        }
        return prefixes;
    }
}
```

I ran this up to 9x9 before space complexity became too much.  It is a very interesting problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help, a very nice solution, gonna save it for future projects. I only needed about 500k combinations from the 16x16, so I ended up picking the combinations randomly and checking them against a hash matrix with lists containing all other combinations that had the current character at that position. Doing this I didn't have to check all other combinations, just the possible matches and got my 500k done during the weekend when I was away.